# Plotting prediction from logistic regression

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I would like to plot y_test and prediction in a scatter plot.
I am using the logistic regression as model.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Spam'])
y = df['Label']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=27)

lr = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear').fit(X_train, y_train)
pred_log = lr.predict(X_test)
```

I have tried as follows

```
## Plot the model

plt.scatter(y_test, pred_log)
plt.xlabel("True Values")
plt.ylabel("Predictions")
```

and I got this:

[image]

that I do not think it is what I should expect.
`y_test` is (250,), similarly `pred_log` is (250,)

Am I considering the wrong variables to plot, or they are right?
I have no idea one what the plot with those four values mean. I would have been expected more dots in the plot, but maybe I am wrong.

Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you know LogisticRegression is a classification algorithm. If you do binary classification it will predict whether predicted class is 0 or 1.If you want to get visualization about how model preform, you should consider [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix).You can't use scatterplot for visualize classification results.

```
import seaborn as sns
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot=True)
```

confusion matrix shows how many labels have correct predictions and how many are wrong.Looking at confusion matrix you can calculate how accurate the model.We can use different metrices like [precision,recall and F1 score](https://blog.exsilio.com/all/accuracy-precision-recall-f1-score-interpretation-of-performance-measures/).

Comment: thanks for your answer and suggestion, Rajith. It makes sense, thanks. May I ask you if it can be also useful to plot ROC with accuracy values?

Comment: The ROC curve is created by plotting the true positive rate (TPR) against the false positive rate (FPR) at various threshold settings.More you get the area more accurate the model.